# Maintain count in python list comprehension

Tags: python

In Python, is there any `counter` available during the list comprehension as it would be in case of a `for` loop?

It would be more clear why I need a counter, with this example:

I wish to achieve the following:

Initial List: `['p', 'q', 'r', 's']`

Desired List: `[(1, 'P'), (2, 'Q'), (3, 'R'), (4, 'S')]`

In the desired list, first element of every tuple are ordinal numbers. If it were just flat list, I could have used `zip` to achieve this. But however, the list I am dealing with is nested, three level deep (think of hierarchical data), and it is generated through list comprehension.

So, I was wondering is there any way to introduce those ordinal numbers during list comprehension. If not, what would be the best possible solution.

P.S. : Here the lower case letters are converted to uppercase, but that is not a part of problem, think of it as just a data conversion.

Code:

```
allObj = Category.objects.all()

tree =[(_, l1.name, [(__, l2.name, [(___, l3.name) for l3 in allObj if l3.parentid == l2.categoryid]) for l2 in allObj if l2.parentid == l1.categoryid]) for l1 in allObj if l1.parentid == None]
```

`allObj` contains data from table category, which in turn contains hierarchical data represented in the form of Adjacency List.

I have put `_` where I need ordinal numbers to be. Notice that the list is nested, so there will be a separate counter at each level represented by 1, 2 & 3 `_`s.

Comment: Have a look at `enumerate(list, 1)` http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: You can almost certainly achieve this using zip. No-one can tell you, if you don't show us your code.

Comment: @Marcin: I have added the code snippet as well.

Comment: It is not trivial to count in this hierarchy saved in a flat list. You should at first build a real hierarchy and then you are able to count on each level.

Comment: @Nobody: This hierarchy comes from a database table as it is stored there in the form of Adjacency List. And what is building a real hierarchy, you mean trees?

Comment: Yes I mean a tree. After building this you could begin counting.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

#### The most basic case

```
[(i, x) for i, x in enumerate(some_list, 1)]
```

#### Apply a filter with an if-statements

```
[(i, x) for i, x in enumerate(some_list, 1) if i > 2]
```

or like this

```
[(i, x) for i, x in enumerate(some_list, 1) if x != 'p']
```

#### A word of advice

Most often you don't need to do this. Instead you just call `enumerate(some_list, 1)` where the enumeration is needed, in a `for` loop for example.

Comment: Nice one, I didn't know about the second argument in enumerate :)

Comment: 9000: Now I don't follow you. According to your answer you know that it's done automaticly (if you did't comment before I added 1 as initial value which I forgot at first)

Comment: Maybe even better: `list(enumerate(map(str.upper, oldList), 1))`. Also note `oldList` to avoid the builtin name `list`.

Comment: Yeah, may be a better solution. Even thought the user asked about comprehension. :) And by list i refered to the list and not to the variable name. But you're right, could be confusing.

Comment: @NiclasNilsson: How would `if` play in the above solution using enumerate().

Comment: btw i found out it seems string addition (concat) operation cannot be done inside a list comprehension?

Answer (score 20):

I was looking to something slightly different when I stumbled upon this answer.

My case was to keep a count based on a condition inside the list comprehension.
Just in case it's useful to someone else, this is how I solved it:

`import itertools
counter = itertools.count(0)
[(next(counter), x) for x in some_list if x != 'p']`

In this way the counter will only be incremented when the condition is met and not at every iteration.

Answer (score 7):

As already showed in the other answers the standard library gives you [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#enumerate), which means that you probably wont even need a list like:

```
[(1, 'P'), (2, 'Q'), (3, 'R'), (4, 'S')]
```

because every time you need to bind the letter with a number related to its position you can just call `enumerate`.
Example:

```
>>> low = ['p', 'q', 'r', 's']
>>> upp = [c.upper() for c in low]
>>>
>>> for i,c in enumerate(upp, 1):
...     print(i,c)
...
1 P
2 Q
3 R
4 S
```

This was just an example, maybe you actually need to that kind of list.

Comment: @user1144616: You're welcome! :) I just saw your updated question (with the code snippet). If you have to stick with that design I wish you all the luck, because it'll be hard to build and even more hard to read. If instead you can refactor your code, take a look at [networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/), maybe it suites your case.

Answer (score 4):

[RTM](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.7/library/functions.html#enumerate): `enumerate(['p', 'q', 'r', 's'], 1)` gives you a generator yielding `(1, 'p'), (2, 'q'), (3, 'r'), (4, 's')`, convert it to `list` to taste.

Comment: I can use `if` to filter elements in case of List comprehension, how would that play here in case of enumerate().

Comment: Filter the incoming sequence, enumerate the result: `enumerate((x for x in some_sequence if is_good(x)), 1)`

Comment: RTFM? He didn't mention `enumerate` in his original post, so how can he RTFM?

Comment: @Rabarberski: He could read the fine manual to learn about `enumerate` and enjoy using it. If you think that the word "RTFM" is rude and condescending, I did not mean it, and such overtones are absent, if "The New Hacker Dictionary" (nee "Jargon File") is [to be believed](http://www.outpost9.com/reference/jargon/jargon_33.html#TAG1524).

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want something like numbering all items, independent of the level of nesting.
Maybe the following will help. Don't forget to create a new `number` for each list comprehension. `next` may be spelled `__next__` in your version of Python.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> number = itertools.count().next
>>> [(number(), [(number(), x + 1) for x in range(y) if x % 2]) for y in range(10) if y % 3]
[(0, []), (1, [(2, 2)]), (3, [(4, 2), (5, 4)]), (6, [(7, 2), (8, 4)]), (9, [(10, 2), (11, 4), (12, 6)]), (13, [(14, 2), (15, 4), (16, 6), (17, 8)])]
```

**Update:**
I know understand that you need different counters for each level of nesting. Just use more than one counter:

```
>>> number1 = itertools.count().__next__
>>> number2 = itertools.count().__next__
>>> print([(number1(), [(number2(), x + 1) for x in range(y) if x % 2]) for y in range(10) if y % 3])
[(0, []), (1, [(0, 2)]), (2, [(1, 2), (2, 4)]), (3, [(3, 2), (4, 4)]), (4, [(5, 2), (6, 4), (7, 6)]), (5, [(8, 2), (9, 4), (10, 6), (11, 8)])]
```

I.e., replace `_` with `number1()` as defined above, `__` with `number2()`, and so on. That's it.

Comment: As of python 3.5+: e.g. number = itertools.count() and [next(number) for i in range(0, 10)].

Answer (score 0):

```
L = ['p', 'q', 'r', 's']
[(i + 1, x) for i, x in enumerate(L)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this help?

```
i = 1

y = range(10)

s = [(i + y.index(x), x**2) for x in y]

print s

>>> [(1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 4), (4, 9), (5, 16), (6, 25), (7, 36), (8, 49), (9, 64), (10, 81)]
```

I have a suspicion that there may be a better way to do this than through comprehensions though.

Answer (score 0):

Great thread! The approved answer and later expansions gave me an idea, which I think might help someone. So here it is.

```
[print('{}. Key: {}, Value: {}'.format(i, k, v)) for i, (k, v) in enumerate(some_list.items(), 1)]
```

The above can be used to get a pretty output of a dictionary. You can use it for debugging, logging, etc... Oh yes, one more possibility, creating a csv file, so your manager can open it in Excel. Managers love their spreadsheets.

Example output:

```
1. Key: AwesomeKey1, Value: AwesomeValue1
2. Key: AwesomeKey2, Value: AwesomeValue2
3. Key: AwesomeKey3, Value: AwesomeValue3
4. Key: AwesomeKey4, Value: AwesomeValue4
5. Key: AwesomeKey5, Value: AwesomeValue5
```