# count in python list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How do i write a list comprehension in python with an inclusion of a 
count = count + 1?

```
print sum([info[count]["count"] for i in info])

# This is the working loop: 

count = 0
lst = []
for i in info:
    num = info[count]["count"]
    # print num
    count = count + 1
    lst.append(num)
print sum(lst)
```

Comment: Use `enumerate`. There must be numerous examples on SO and in the python docs.

Comment: What is the point of `count`? Why not just use `i`?!

Comment: as suggested by @jonrsharpe, why don't you use `sum(i["count"] for i in info)`?

Comment: In my opinion, a related but better posed question is already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197844/maintain-count-in-python-list-comprehension). One can probably extract what one needs from the answers provided to the linked page.

Answer (score 4):

```
    >>> a = ['a','b','c']
    >>> v = ['a','e','i','o','u']
    >>> len(a)
    3
    >>> sum([1 for x in a if x in v])
    2
```

Comment: It is helpful to describe what is going on with your code. This will give context and help the OP as well as people that come across this answer in the future.

Comment: For me the result is `1`, which is the expected result in my case. Not sure how the code above could give `2` as result given that only value 'a' is in collection `a` and collection `v`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not follow why you use `i` in `i in info` together with `count`. If `info` is enumerable and enumerating has the same effect as accessing with a zero offset index (like you seem to do with `count`, you can rewrite your loop like:

```
lst = []
for infoi in info:
    num = infoi["count"]
    # print num
    lst.append(num)

print sum(lst)
```

Now you can convert this to the following list comprehension:

```
sum([infoi["count"] for infoi in info])
```

Finally you do not need to *materialize* the comprehension to a list, `sum` can work on a generator:

```
sum(infoi["count"] for infoi in info)
```

This can be more efficient, since you will *not* construct a list first with all the values: `sum` will enumerate over all items and thus will result in constant memory usage.