# How can I add a iteration count to list comprehensions in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Here is my current code:

My issue is, I'm practicing List Comprehension but am confused as to why "count += 1" does not work in this type of format:

```
[count += 1 for elem in li]
[count += 1 and print(elem) for elem in li]
```

I am, however, able to do it in a normal for loop as I did below. Can someone explain how I can accomplish the function below with a list comprehension?

(The above lines of code with the list comprehension format are not necessarily related to accum(s).)

```
def accum(s):
    count = 0
    li = []
    for char in s:
        count += 1
        li.append(char.upper() + char.lower() * (count-1))
    return "-".join(li)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comprehensions take an *expression* as its first element; `count += 1` is a *statement*.

Instead, use `enumerate`, which takes a generator producing `x` and returns a generator producing `(i, x)` where `i` is the index:

```
'-'.join(char.upper() + char.lower() * i for i, char in enumerate(s))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for count,char in enumerate(s):
    li.append(char.upper() + char.lower() * (count-1))
```

use `enumerate` for this type of thing

as a list comprehension

```
  [char.upper() + char.lower() * (count-1) for count,char in enumerate(s)]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to maintain count in python list comprehension, use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

check this [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197844/maintain-count-in-python-list-comprehension)

and try this code

`"-".join((elem.upper() + elem.lower() * i) for ii, elem in enumerate(li))`