# How can I find a number in a specific position in Python

Tags: python

I need read a log with this structure:

w00041c0da70021002206900691

i use this code for read but does not work

```
results = [line[10:13] for line in f.readlines() if line[10:13] == "7002"]
```

I need the number of lines that have the number 7002 in position 10 to 13

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('file.log','r') as logFile:
    output = logFile.read()
    #Iterate over lines and slice each row's data
    #logData[10:14] == '7002'
```

Comment: Is it necessary to open as logfile?

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0
for line in f.readlines():
    if line[10:13] == "7002":
        count += 1
print("Count :",count)
```

if you want to do the count in list comprehension , have a look at [Maintain count in python list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197844/maintain-count-in-python-list-comprehension)

Comment: I tested this code and does not work for "7002" but if i use only one number example "7" work fine. it's very strange